# Getting duplicate data in Angular HTML table

Tags: html, angular

For my application once I login to the Identity Server, a token will be passed and that token needs to be passed to access the API.
After getting the response from the API, when I try to display that data in the table I am getting duplicate records. Can you help me understand why?

Here is my .ts code

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  [x: string]: any;
  constructor(public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  value1: any = null;
  cols: any[];
  user: any[];
  adduser(): void {
    console.log("inside adduser function");
    this.router.navigate(['/addrole']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': this.authService.getAuthorizationHeaderValue() });
    console.log({ headers });
    this.http.get("http://localhost:5500/api/Users", { headers: headers }).subscribe(response => {
      this.response = response;
      this.users = this.response.users;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'userName', header: 'userId', width: '40%' },
      { field: 'email', header: 'Email', width: '15%' },
      { field: 'phoneNumber', header: 'PhoneNumber', width: '15%' },
    ];

  }
}
```

.HTML Code

```
</div>
<button pButton type="button" label="Search"></button>
<div style="margin-top: 50px"></div>
<p-table [value]="users">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr> 
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" >
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.phoneNumber }}</td>
    </tr>enter code here
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Output I am getting

[image]

Comment: What does `console.log(this.users);` log?  I don't see anything in your code that would duplicate the data.  Even if your request was called multiple times, you are re-assigning this.users each time.

Comment: are you sure it is angular? Because it seems your api is responding duplicated data